# Split parsing logic into separate files Node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

Right now my code creates a stream of from an XML file containing multiple documents and makes it into one XML document. It then passes that string to an XML parser which allows me to retrieve data from the XML stream. I would like to modularize my application by seperating the logic for creating the xml stream and the logic for the xml parser. Heres my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var split = require("split");
var util = require("util");
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;
var XmlStream = require('xml-stream');
var parseXml;


// Create a file stream and pass it to XmlStream
var streamXmlFile = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'ipg140107.xml'));


util.inherits(CombineXmlDocs, Transform);
function CombineXmlDocs () {
    Transform.call(this, { "objectMode": true });
    this.currLine = 0;
}

CombineXmlDocs.prototype._transform = function (line, encoding, processed) {
    this.currLine++;
    if (this.currLine === 3) {
        this.push('<week-of-patents>\n');
    }
    if (this.currLine < 3 || (line.indexOf('<?xml') === -1 && line.indexOf('<!DOCTYPE') === -1)) { // handle first line
        this.push(line + '\n');
    }
    processed(); // we're done processing the current line
};

CombineXmlDocs.prototype._flush = function(cb) {
    cb();
};

// streamXmlFile.pipe(split()).pipe(new CombineXmlDocs()).pipe(process.stdout);
parseXml = new XmlStream(streamXmlFile.pipe(split()).pipe(new CombineXmlDocs()));
// parseXml = new XmlStream(streamXmlFile);

parseXml.on('endElement: date', function(date) {
  console.log(date.$text);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by creating a stream that concatenates the xml doc and exports a stream. Then required that file in my app.js and used the exported stream to pass to my XML parser.

app.js code:

```
var createParsableXml = require('./createParsableXml.js');
var XmlParserStream = require('xml-stream');
var parseXml;

// create a parsable xml stream using xml-stream node.js module
parseXml = new XmlParserStream(createParsableXml.streamConcatXml);

parseXml.on('endElement: date', function(date) {
  console.log(date.$text);
});
```

createParsableXml.js code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// allows for stream parsing on a line by line basis
var split = require('split');

var util = require('util');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
var streamXmlFile = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'ipg140107.xml'));


util.inherits(CombineXmlDocs, Transform);
function CombineXmlDocs () {
    Transform.call(this, { "objectMode": true });
    this.currLine = 0;
}

// logic for parsing concatenated uspto xml docs into one xml doc
CombineXmlDocs.prototype._transform = function (line, encoding, processed) {
    // removes xml and doctype declarations except for the first instance, adds root element to doc
    this.currLine++;
    if (this.currLine === 3) {
        this.push('<week-of-patents>\n');
    }
    if (this.currLine < 3 || (line.indexOf('<?xml') === -1 && line.indexOf('<!DOCTYPE') === -1)) { // handle first line
        this.push(line + '\n');
    }
    processed(); // we're done processing the current line
};

CombineXmlDocs.prototype._flush = function(cb) {
    cb();
};

exports.streamConcatXml = streamXmlFile.pipe(split()).pipe(new CombineXmlDocs());
```